# Excluding an Element based on previousElementSibling

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script that selects all paragraph elements that descend from a section element. I would like it to exclude all paragraph elements that have a previousElementSibling of a heading tag.

The working part of the script, with my test console.logs is

```
var allParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll('section > p');
var firstParagraph = allParagraphs[0];

for (i=0; i < allParagraphs.length; i++) {

    var prevElement = allParagraphs[i].previousElementSibling;
    console.log(prevElement);

    if (i !=0 && i != allParagraphs.length && i % 3 == 0 ) {
        // Work Magic on the Paragraph Elements
    }
}
```

What I want to do though is exclude any paragraph element that is preceded by a heading element,  in particular.

When I run the script above, my console.log output will list everything correctly. What I cannot figure out how to actually test that value for ""/"h3"/etc.

I tried using some other properties like .localName and .nodeName. When I add those to console.log:

```
console.log(prevElement.localName);
console.log(prevElement.nodeName);
```

Both of these result in an error in the console that prevElement is null.

I also tried adding:

```
&& prevElement != '<h3'>
```

to the if conditions to see if that worked, as well as 'h3'/'H3' and none of them did.

Is there a way to either exclude h3+p from the initial document.querySelectorAll or to filter it out in the if/then condition?

Note: I do not want to do this in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to either exclude h3+p from the initial `document.querySelectorAll`?

You could use the selector

```
section > p:first-child, section > *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3):not(h4):not(h5):not(h6) + p
```

> …or to filter it out in the if/then condition?

Your approach with `prevElement.nodeName != "h3"` was fine, but you need to take care of the paragraphs that are the first element in their section and don't have a `.previousElementSibling`. Just test for `prevElement == null || …`.

Comment: How did you arrive at that long selector? Why wouldn't 'section > p:not(h3+p)' work?

Comment: @belinus: [`:not` only allows simple selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation) - I'd loved to use `:not(h1,h2,h3,…)` but it doesn't work. The Selectors 4 draft loosens this a bit, but I don't think it's implemented yet. So I just took your description and translated it literally to a selector…

Comment: That's the fun of CSS vs JS :P. Is the p:first-child needed or can the second part of the selector? p is the first child of section.

Comment: `p:first-child` is necessary, as the `* + p` part doesn't match first children.

Comment: I see. I tried adding the prevElement == null to the if conditional and still got the error message though.